# Jquery - How to find span inside div by special text and change background of span after it

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is entire html code and TextVar Variable.

```
TextVar = 1000
```

How can I find `span` with `ImgStylePicker` and change `background-color` of it if text of before span with `Rangeto` class is equal with `TextVar`?

```
   <div id="Classified">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <span class="Rangefrom">1</span>-<span class="Rangeto">1000</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="ImgStylePicker"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <span class="Rangefrom">1000</span>-<span class="Rangeto">2000</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="ImgStylePicker"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <span class="Rangefrom">2000</span>-<span class="Rangeto">3000</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="ImgStylePicker"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: See jQuery, [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$(".Rangeto:contains(" + TextVar + ")").closest(".row").find(".ImgStylePicker").css("background-color", "yellow")
```

This will look if any element with the class `Rangeto` contains the value of `TextVar`

**Demo**

```js
var TextVar = 1000;

$(".Rangeto:contains(" + TextVar + ")").closest(".row").find(".ImgStylePicker").css("background-color", "yellow")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Classified">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <span class="Rangefrom">1</span>-<span class="Rangeto">1000</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <span class="ImgStylePicker">s</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <span class="Rangefrom">1000</span>-<span class="Rangeto">2000</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <span class="ImgStylePicker">s</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <span class="Rangefrom">2000</span>-<span class="Rangeto">3000</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <span class="ImgStylePicker">s</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: TextVar is a integer (see the question) and $(this).closest(".row").find(".Rangeto").text() will give you a string value

Comment: @AKA Updated the answer, Take a look

Comment: Thats wrong you dont need each function to make that

Comment: @SilverSurfer Before you question my method then you should read the question and make sure you answer to match the required result.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen and SilverSufer, relax guys.. you are here to help people not to fight with each other. Please point each other technically instead of just blaming.

Answer (score 0):

Here a one liner solution, you dont need `each()` function

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var TextVar = 1000
  $(".ImgStylePicker").closest(".form-group").find(".Rangeto:contains(" + TextVar + ")").css("background-color", "green") 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Classified">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <span class="Rangefrom">1</span>-<span class="Rangeto">1000</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="ImgStylePicker"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <span class="Rangefrom">1000</span>-<span class="Rangeto">2000</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="ImgStylePicker"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <span class="Rangefrom">2000</span>-<span class="Rangeto">3000</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="ImgStylePicker"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: He want to change the bg color of `ImgStylePicker` not `Rangeto`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this simple code!

```
var TextVar = 1000;
$(".Rangeto:contains(" + TextVar + ")").closest(".row").find(".ImgStylePicker").css("background-color", "red");
```

Comment: can any one comment why this answer was downvoted? although this is not mine anser :)

Comment: wow! i don't know, but look back first answer, seem him updated his answer follow my style!
Goodluck!

Comment: this is wrong dude. I dont know how to complain this to stackoverflow but that's really bad. Anyway you keep helping peoples

Comment: What makes your answer so awesome that is better then the accepted answer that was posted an hour before yours? I admit that both your answer and the accepted answer are awfully in layout and don't explain what the code does, at all. On the plus side: the accepted answer provides a working code snippet, yours don't. There are plenty of reasons to down vote this. /cc @UmerHayyat

Comment: Thank you @Rene,

I don't want to argue, but I have seen the first answer using `forEach` I'm sure it's not good. That's why I gave this answer, then I saw him updated his answer same my answer. Missing snippet, that's my fault!

Comment: @Umer Hayyat I will continue to answer when capacity allow! tks dude! :)